# UIScrollView and UIImageView - move horizontally

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have UIScrollView with UIImageView on it. I set image in code and it can have different width (height is always the same). I want to do it scrollable (eg. see only part of it and drag it to left / right to see the rest).

I have this code performed after image change:

```
float x = self.imageView.frame.origin.x;
float y = self.imageView.frame.origin.y;
float w = scaleImg.size.width;
float h = scaleImg.size.height;

self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
self.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h);


w = self.frame.size.width;
h = self.scrollView.frame.size.height;

[self.scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(w + 20, h)];
```

Problem is, that it didn't scroll correctly (I think it didn't scroll at all). And after I scroll, my image is resized, not respecting the frame I have set above.

I am using iOS7, storyboard, autolayout.

Comment: I think you can try setting scrollview content-offset with animation while scrolling. Make content-offset depending upon the current and next/previous image size. Disable autolayout if you are resizing image in your code .

Comment: If I disable autolayout, rest od my GUI will be incorrect.

Comment: so do not resize in code and try UIImageView contentMode  AspectFit .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the image to fit the scrollview and be scrollable left and right only you should create the image view with height same as the scrollview and width scaled accordingly to the image. Try something like this:

```
    UIImage *image;
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
    UIImageView *imageView;

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(.0f,
                                                              .0f,
                                                              scrollView.frame.size.height*image.size.width/image.size.height,
                                                              scrollView.frame.size.height)];//fixed height
    imageView.image = image;
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size;
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake((scrollView.contentSize.width-scrollView.frame.size.width)*.5f, .0f);//scroll to center
```

Note I designed this only for images which have proportionally larger width then scrollview. If that is not always the case you should create a specific logic for other images (either background is visible or it is scrollable in Y coordinate).

Comment: Edit: only change I have done is contentMode set to UIViewContentModeLeft. With your solution, it shrinks the image.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should remove the following lines:

```
w = self.frame.size.width;
h = self.scrollView.frame.size.height;
```

`scrollView`'s content size should reflect size of enclosed content, i.e. it should be `scaleImg.size.width` & `scaleImg.size.height`.

Answer (score 0):

you given the w as the width for both scrollview and imageview....content size should be more than scroll view.Try giving imageview width more than scrollview.